# How to make negative values in stacked bar chart start at previous stack?

Tags: javafx, charts

I want to visualize incoming vs outgoing amounts per month in a stacked bar chart, but also the difference should be immediately visible.

I'm using the following sample code:

```
public class Statistics extends Application {
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final StackedBarChart<String, Number> sbc = new StackedBarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    final XYChart.Series<String, Number> incoming = new XYChart.Series<>();
    final XYChart.Series<String, Number> outgoing = new XYChart.Series<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        xAxis.setLabel("Month");
        xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                Arrays.asList("Jan", "Feb", "Mar")));
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");
        incoming.setName("Incoming");
        incoming.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 25601.34));
        incoming.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb2", 20148.82));
        incoming.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar2", 10000));
        outgoing.setName("Outgoing");
        outgoing.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", -7401.85));
        outgoing.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb2", -1941.19));
        outgoing.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar2", -5263.37));
        Scene scene = new Scene(sbc, 800, 600);
        sbc.getData().addAll(incoming, outgoing);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Which results in:

[image: Stacked bar chart with negative values below zero]

As you can see, the negative *outgoing* values are displayed below zero instead of being subtracted from the positive *incoming* values, which makes it hard to see the delta between the two.

What I want instead is that a bar for a negative value starts at the top of a bar for a positive value, but as they would overlap then, also apply an offset along the x-axis. At the example of the "Jan" series this should look similar to:

[image]

I was playing around with `getNode().setTranslateX/Y()`, but that does not seem to be a good solution as the translation units is not ticks in the chart, but something else.

How can I create a "stacked" bar chart like in the second image in an elegant way?

Comment: BTW, I meanwhile noticed this kind of chart is very similar to what is called a waterfall chart, which is not directly supported in JavaFX, but can be created by using [JFreeChart](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartWaterfallChartDemo.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Your question is really cool!*

So, here I want to share my solution using a *BarChart* instead of a *StackedBarChart*. It might be a bit hacky, but it is the only one that worked for me.

The first thing that came to my mind was to just simply take the bar and change its Y coordinate, but unfortunately we cannot access bars directly. So after digging through the source code of `XYChart` I found that all of the chart's content are located in `Group plotContent`, but the getter for that is `protected`. In this situation the one of things to do is to extend the class and increase the scope of method. So (finally), here the code comes:

```
public class Statistics extends Application {
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    // here I use the modified version of chart
    final ModifiedBarChart<String, Number> chart = new ModifiedBarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    final XYChart.Series<String, Number> incoming = new XYChart.Series<>();
    final XYChart.Series<String, Number> outgoing = new XYChart.Series<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        xAxis.setLabel("Month");
        xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                Arrays.asList("Jan", "Feb", "Mar")));
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");


        incoming.setName("Incoming");
        incoming.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 25601.34));
        incoming.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 20148.82));
        incoming.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 10000));

        outgoing.setName("Outgoing");
        // To set the min value of yAxis you can either set lowerBound to 0 or don't use negative numbers here
        outgoing.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", -7401.85));
        outgoing.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", -1941.19));
        outgoing.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", -5263.37));

        chart.getData().addAll(incoming, outgoing);

        Scene scene = new Scene(chart, 800, 600);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // and here I iterate over all plotChildren elements
        // note, that firstly all positiveBars come, then all negative ones
        int dataSize = incoming.getData().size();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
            Node positiveBar = chart.getPlotChildren().get(i);
            // subtract 1 to make two bars y-axis aligned
            chart.getPlotChildren().get(i + dataSize).setLayoutY(positiveBar.getLayoutY() - 1);
        }

    }

    // note, that I extend BarChart here
    private static class ModifiedBarChart<X, Y> extends BarChart<X, Y> {

        public ModifiedBarChart(@NamedArg("xAxis") Axis<X> xAxis, @NamedArg("yAxis") Axis<Y> yAxis) {
            super(xAxis, yAxis);
        }

        public ModifiedBarChart(@NamedArg("xAxis") Axis<X> xAxis, @NamedArg("yAxis") Axis<Y> yAxis, @NamedArg("data") ObservableList<Series<X, Y>> data) {
            super(xAxis, yAxis, data);
        }

        public ModifiedBarChart(@NamedArg("xAxis") Axis<X> xAxis, @NamedArg("yAxis") Axis<Y> yAxis, @NamedArg("data") ObservableList<Series<X, Y>> data, @NamedArg("categoryGap") double categoryGap) {
            super(xAxis, yAxis, data, categoryGap);
        }


        @Override
        public ObservableList<Node> getPlotChildren() {
            return super.getPlotChildren();
        }
    }
```

The result:
[image: The result]

Comment: Just one minor comment, it seems you have to use `setLayoutY(positiveBar.getLayoutY() - 1)` to make the *Incoming* and *Outgoing* bars align on the same y-axis value.

Comment: Yeah, now I can see a small difference in y-coordinates)  probably it's because of x-axis own width.